# How to set Date range in bendemboski Date Slider widget in android

Tags: android, android-widget

I am using DateSlider widget from [Here](https://github.com/bendemboski/DateSlider)

It is nice widget but I want to set Date range to select date,How can I set date range in this widget.I am using MonthYearDateSlider in this widget.

or any datePicker widget is there in android which allow to user to select only year and month within some range.